# How to avoid REST API authentication when user is already authenticated in TFS dashboard

Tags: javascript, html, tfs

I'm writing a TFS widget (HTML & Javascript), when I add the widget to my dashboard, I'm correctly logged in TFS.
The widget make a simple GET API such as:

https://{account}.VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis[/{area}]/{resource}?api-version={version}

But the response is unauthorized. 
Why I've to authenticate me again? The widget is launched from my TFS dashboard...
I don't want to put the credential again, indeed if I open a browser tab and paste the API in the URL it works...
There is a way to solve this problem?

!!!!UPDATE:
I try this code but I see always unauthorized (P.S. from the console I see the token):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>

    "use strict";

    VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformStyles: true
    });

    VSS.require(["VSS/Authentication/Services"],
        function (VSS_Auth_Service) {
            VSS.getAccessToken().then(function(token){
                // Format the auth header
                var authHeader = VSS_Auth_Service.authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);

                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var fileData = this.responseText;

                        alert(fileData);

                    }
                };

                xhttp.open("GET", "https://........./_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
                console.log(authHeader);
                xhttp.send();
                // Add token as an Authorization header to your request
            });
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="widget">
    <h1 class="title">Builds</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether you have `vso.build` and `vso.build_execute` scopes.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initiating a REST call? It's better to use Rest Client API. It also matters which resource you are asking from server, there must be an specific scope set in extension for it.

Also tell me which authentication are you using? Use oAuth for this purpose, VSS SDK will give you oAuth AccessToken based on your credentials saved in TFS. You have to use that token for all of your REST calls.

Comment: I use the XMLHttpRequest(); for make a simple GET. I don't understand why I've to authenticate me again. BTW have you a javascript oAuth snippet example?

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate using oAuth token. Sample is bellow:

```
 var getWorkItem1 = function (access_token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_apis/wit/workitems/1?api-version=4.1',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var b = "Bearer "+access_token;

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", b);
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        var workItemType = data.fields['System.WorkItemType'];
    }).error(function (e) {

    });
}
```

For obtaining AccessToken use Core Client SDK, please refer to below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=vsts